# Liferay: BooleanQuery MUST NOT some values

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, liferay, liferay-6, booleanquery

I want to create a search with multiple values, for example:

I want to search in database all Articles that do not contain the category:

Car
Bus
motorcycle
truck
On database exist articles with a category 'Car' foe example but not with category 'Car' and 'Bus' (One Article & One Category). So ... I need to make some like to "OR" (I need all articles that do not have category with 'Car' OR with 'Bus' OR with 'truck' etc ..)

We're using Liferay 6.1 for this search.

Comment: What is your mapping? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't completely understand the description given. If you are trying to fetch records that do not have a category like CAR, BUS, TRUCK etc. You can try by negating your query.

```
-category:(car bus truck motorcycle)
```

The minus( **-** ) sign placed before category will negate the search. So it returns records that do not have these categories.